# Bash Script with multiple variables

Tags: mysql, bash

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Ask for username, database, and password for SQL
- Attempt SQLDUMP
- If failed due to specific table, ask for which table, once entered, add it to script.
- Run again automatically after adding table
- If failed again, ask for new table, add table to list
- Continue this process until successful

Here's what I've made so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

:dbase
echo "What is the Database name?"
read db1
goto :PW

:PW
echo "what is the password?"

read p1


PASSWORD=${p1}
HOST=mysql
USER=root
DATABASE=${db1}
DB_FILE=SQLDump.sql
EXCLUDED_TABLES=(
)

IGNORED_TABLES_STRING=''
for TABLE in "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[@]}"
do :
   IGNORED_TABLES_STRING+=" --ignore-table=${DATABASE}.${TABLE}"
done

echo "Dump structure"
mysqldump --compress --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --single-transaction --no-data --routines --extended-insert=false --max_allowed_packet=2048M ${DATABASE} > ${DB_FILE}

echo "Dump content"
mysqldump --compress --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --extended-insert=false --max_allowed_packet=2048M ${DATABASE} --no-create-info --skip-triggers ${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} >> ${DB_FILE}
pause
alias ll='ls -lah'
ll *.sql

:choice
set /P c=Do you see your file[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :yes
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :no
goto :choice


:yes

echo "Awesome, I'll delete this script now."
rm -rf /srv/SQLDump
echo "I have successfully deleted SQLDUMP."
pause
exit

:no
echo "What was the name of the table that failed?"
read $table1
set /P c=Was there another?[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :t2
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :continue


PASSWORD=${p1}
HOST=mysql
USER=root
DATABASE=${db1}
DB_FILE=SQLDump.sql
EXCLUDED_TABLES=(
${table1}
)

IGNORED_TABLES_STRING=''
for TABLE in "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[@]}"
do :
   IGNORED_TABLES_STRING+=" --ignore-table=${DATABASE}.${TABLE}"
done

echo "Dump structure"
mysqldump --compress --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --single-transaction --no-data --routines --extended-insert=false --max_allowed_packet=2048M ${DATABASE} > ${DB_FILE}

echo "Dump content"
mysqldump --compress --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --extended-insert=false --max_allowed_packet=2048M ${DATABASE} --no-create-info --skip-triggers ${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} >> ${DB_FILE}
pause
alias ll='ls -lah'
ll *.sql

:choice
set /P c=Do you see your file[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :yes
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :no
goto :choice
```

It's obviously not finished. I ran into an issue where i'm calling the script over and over again in order to add multiple tables. I know there's a workaround, but as I'm self taught, I haven't been able to figure it out. Ideas?

Comment: You seem to mix batch and Bash.

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @BenjaminW. fixed, thank you.
Cyrus will it show me how to add multi variable creation automatically?

Comment: You've fixed the title, but you're using batch/powershell constructs such as `goto`, `:` tags and `if /I` / `set /P`, all of which don't exist in Bash.

Comment: If you want to write a pure bash script (this looks like a mixture of everything) you need to use `while` loop, `goto` won't work! Also, if the output of `mysqldump` gives out the name of the failed tables (I guess it did, didn't?) you can use `grep` command to find out the name of the failed table(s) automatically, requiring no input from the end user.

Comment: @MojoNojo : Did you ever bother to **execute** your script once? If you run it with `bash YOURSCRIPT`, already the first statement, `:dbase` will output an error message that there is no command of this name.

Answer (score 0):

To restart your script it have to support options, so i'd suggest this approach

```
#!/bin/bash

# get options if restarter
while [[ $@ ]]; do
    case $1 in
        --name) name="$2";;
        --pass) pass="$2";;
        --tabl) tables+=("$2");;
    esac
    shift
done

# get initial data when started first time
[[ $pass ]] || read -p 'What is the password? '      pass
[[ $name ]] || read -p 'What is the Database name? ' name

options=( --name "$name" --pass "$pass" )

# your code here
# add tables to tables to options array like this
# options+=(--tabl "table name")

# and restart script with options like this

$0 "${options[@]}"
```